# How to publish an app that uses Service account JSON onto google workspace marketplace?

Tags: service-accounts, google-workspace-add-ons

I am trying to publish a web app publicly that uses a service JSON to update the user's settings by calling the web app api. This will be a service json that I have configured to have domain wide delegation in my google admin portal.

In order to change the user's email settings, I had to impersonate them using the service account json. I have also made the service json compatible with the google workspace marketplace.
[image]

This allowed me to call the url using a get call to the following api and passing the email as a query parameter:

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/<app_id>/exec?email=test@example.com
```

I have also configured the app to be admin install only

My question is as follows:

If an admin installs the workspace app, can I use the same service JSON that I have created in this project to access the person's external domain users? How would the domain delegation work?

If they can't use the same service JSON, does that mean they need to manually enter the service JSON into the google workspace app? How would they go about it?

Comment: Have you reviewed the docs for [Set up domain-wide delegation for a service account](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#optional_set_up_domain-wide_delegation_for_a_service_account)? If not, the service account won't be able to access **any person's _EXTERNAL DOMAIN_ users** since the `Service Account` (with _domain-wide delegation_) can only access the users' data that belong to the Google Workspace Admin Console where the accounts & _domain-wide delegation_ were setup to. Otherwise, they need to create a version of your app w/ their own `service account`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I know this is the case if the app isnt published (using a python script). I am not sure then whats the use of the Google Workspace Marketplace Oauth Client? There has been similar attempts here too - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54634876/gsuite-marketplace-app-with-service-account). Is there a way to publish your service account json to the gsuite marketplace app and allow the admin to install it domain wide without them creating a service account themself?

Comment: Based on the documentation, you setup the `Google Workspace Marketplace Oauth Client` to give the **Google Workspace Marketplace API** ability to perform a **domain-wide installation** of your app/add-on. Meaning, you can distribute your app/add-on to your domain users & choose who can either auto-install your app Or who can see it an an available app that they can manually install themselves _(e.g. when go to `https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/mydomainapps`)_.

Comment: Back to your question, **Is there a way to publish your service account json to the gsuite marketplace app and allow the admin to install it domain wide without them creating a service account themself?** It is not possible as you would need to create that `Service Account` at `https://console.cloud.google.com/` under the external domain. There's no automated process in deploying a **single** `Service Account` as this could apparently lead to a security breach, given the external domain is a totally different entity _(if I have understood it correctly)_.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How would I do operations that require a service account? How do you publish a service account json into the google workspace marketplace? And how do apps that call apis that require a service account credential work? Could you please tell me how I should distribute the app that requires a service account json?

Comment: Is there a way to distribute an app with service account json? How would the workflow work then? Could you please explain it in detail thanks

Comment: I could allow domain wide installation before adding the service account json. Does that mean that without a service account json you can’t have domain wide installation? This setting is under service account tab

Comment: I am no expert on this to be honest, so I won't be able to further help you with this. But as an overview, your app first should have authorization codes that uses a service account such as from this [tutorial](https://www.labnol.org/code/20375-service-accounts-google-apps-script) for it to use service account json. I highly suggest you [Overview: Publish an app](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/how-to-publish) Or [Contact the experts](https://cloud.google.com/contact) to address all your Google Cloud Console settings/setup-related concerns that is not about Google APIs.

Comment: @qwerty did you happen to find answer to your queries? If so, I'd also like to know!